# Powershell Get Value of Object

Tags: powershell

I have an Object array that has the following output.
Initially the output was like this:

```
@{AvailabilityGroup=A; Name=1},@{AvailabilityGroup=B; Name=2},@{AvailabilityGroup=C; Name=3},@{AvailabilityGroup=D; Name=4},@{AvailabilityGroup=E; Name=5},  @{AvailabilityGroup=F; Name=6}
```

I did a split on the comma and the output now look like this.

```
@{AvailabilityGroup=A; Name=1}
@{AvailabilityGroup=B; Name=2}
@{AvailabilityGroup=C; Name=3}
@{AvailabilityGroup=D; Name=4}
@{AvailabilityGroup=E; Name=5}
@{AvailabilityGroup=F; Name=6}
```

How do I get the value of the objects?

Comment: Can you show us how you obtain that output? Sounds to me that you are stringifying an object array where basically you can get the values from the objects simply by using their array index and next use dot-notation to get the values. Something like `$array[0].AvailabilityGroup` --> `A` and `$array[0].Name` --> `1`. What does `$array[0].GetType()` show you?

Comment: Show us how you constructed the array in the first place

Comment: I'm basically using a DbaTools Powershell cmdlets that I'm running against some SQL AG that looks something like this. The `$aglist` array is how I'm obtaining the output.
`$aglist = @()
$AGs = Get-DbaAvailabilityGroup -SqlInstance SQL1 -IsPrimary -SqlCredential $creds | Where { $_.IsDistributedAvailabilityGroup -eq $false }  |  Get-DbaAgReplica 
foreach ($AG in $AGs){
  $aglist +=  $AG | Select AvailabilityGroup, Name
}
`

Comment: @ITPRO85, these commands do not explain why you end up with _stringified_ objects. As an aside: you can simplify to `$aglist = Get-DbaAvailabilityGroup -SqlInstance SQL1 -IsPrimary -SqlCredential $creds | Where { $_.IsDistributedAvailabilityGroup -eq $false } | Get-DbaAgReplica | Select AvailabilityGroup, Name`

Comment: @Theo when running $array[0].gettype(), I'm getting the following.

`IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType`
`-------- -------- ----                                     --------`
`True     True     Char                                     System.ValueType`

Comment: @mklement0, I'm using a SCORCH (System Center) and when this is executed in a runbook, it's been flattened before its passed to another Activity in the runbook.

Comment: @ITPRO85, that implies that `$array` is actually a _string_. If you cannot avoid stringification, use a _structured_ text format such as JSON for output - the default stringification of custom objects is meant for _display_ only, and cannot be parsed robustly.

Comment: It appears that you have an array of hashes. Why do you need to treat them like a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, your array has strings like `"@{AvailabilityGroup=A; Name=1}"`?

If so, you can do [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.4) to evaluate the string as a command (for example `Invoke-Expression "ls"` would be the same as `ls`) like so:

```
foreach ($objStr in $yourArray) {
    $object = Invoke-Expression $objStr;

    # Now you can just access the fields like so:
    $object.AvailabilityGroup;
    $object.Name;
}
```

Let me know if this makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems like I'm getting the message as before, which is, The term 'A' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Comment: The complete declaration of that line of code is `$arrayList =  "@{AvailabilityGroup=A; Name=1},@{AvailabilityGroup=B; Name=2},@{AvailabilityGroup=C; Name=3},@{AvailabilityGroup=D; Name=4},@{AvailabilityGroup=E; Name=5},  @{AvailabilityGroup=F; Name=6}"`

Comment: Hmm, can you change the $arrayList to be this instead `$arrayList =  "@{AvailabilityGroup='A'; Name=1},@{AvailabilityGroup='B'; Name=2},@{AvailabilityGroup='C'; Name=3},@{AvailabilityGroup='D'; Name=4},@{AvailabilityGroup='E'; Name=5},  @{AvailabilityGroup='F'; Name=6}"`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. That worked!  I guess I need to figure out why the Powershell cmdlet is producing the output the wrong way.